# Как вывести количество товаров в категории ocStore 2.3.0.2.3

Tags: php, opencart, count, ocstore

Есть допустим страница категории "*apple*".

my-site.ru/apple

На этой странице отображаются товары только из соответствующей категории.

Допустим под заголовком `<h1>Apple</h1>` в тег **`<p></p>`**
хочу выводить количество товаров в этой категории

Чтобы было наглядно вот пример:

```
<h1>Apple</h1>
<p class="goods-count"><span>100</span> товаров</p> // в span вывели кол-во
```

На страницах категории в схемах вывожу в левую колонку показ всех категорий для навигации по сайту. В этой колонке ВЫВОДИТСЯ количество товаров рядом с названиями категорий. Этой я сделал в

**админка-система-настройки-опции-счётчик товаров в категории-да**.

Но как мне вывести в другое место на сайте количество товаров, просматриваемой категории не могу понять. Кто-нить поможет? В каком файле искать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, то что вы поставили галочку, это всё верно.

Дальше будет гайд, как это сделать. Обратите внимание я делаю на стандартном шаблоне, поэтому некоторые моменты могут отличаться.

Теперь открывайте файл `catalog\controller\product\category.php`
Ищем строку, которая начинается так: `$data['results'] =`. Она там по идее должная быть одна. Ниже этой строки добавляем новую:

```
$data['product_total'] = $product_total;
```

Переменная `$product_total` хранит общее количество товара в категории и нам нужно было передать её в шаблон.

***Должно получится так:***

```
$data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));
$data['product_total'] = $product_total;
```

Теперь открывайте файл `catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl` (шаблон страницы категории).
**Обратите внимание, я правлю "дефолтный шаблон". В вашем случаи правьте свой.**

Ищите строку, где у вас выводится название категории. В моём случаи это `<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>`. Теперь я туда добавляю количество товара, например:

```
<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?> (<?php echo $product_total; ?>)</h1>
```

Должно было получиться что-то типо такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Действительно я искал дефолтное решение, как прочитал Ваш ответ, сразу же сделал как Вы и написали, нашел в category.php эту переменную и вывожу ее в category.tpl (шаблон у меня стандартный), но на странице выводится ошибка ***UNDEFINED VARIABLE: PRODUCT_TOTAL IN /HOME/S/SKYTECHSU/KOREA/PUBLIC_HTML/CATALOG/VIEW/THEME/DEFAULT/TEMPLATE/PRODUCT/CATEGORY.TPL***

Comment: @МайклМиллер По ошибка ясно, что переменной нет. Вы точно добавили строку? И кеш opencart сбрасывали?

Comment: Да, добавил точно, не уверен правильно ли это сделал      $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'),
            $data['product_total'] = $product_total,                           
            ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

Comment: @МайклМиллер ой, вей) Не так, я обновил ответ. Посмотрите.

Comment: Теперь ругается на строку ***system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/product/category.php on line 231***

Comment: @МайклМиллер обновите кеш Opencart. Код должен работать, сейчас попробовал.

Comment: Прошу прощения, ругался на другую строку, удалил ее и все ок, выводится кол-во там где нужно. Премного благодарен Вам, мистер! ПреогромнейшеЕ спасибо Вам!

Comment: Можно вопрос по теме? Вот там где по стандарту выводится кол-во рядом с названием каждой категории в левой колонке - кол-во выводится просто так без каких-либо тегов, (например: ***iPhone (100)***), вот мне чтобы стилизовать только цифры (кол-ва) хотелось бы обернуть в какой-то тег, но пока не нашел нормального варианта. То есть на jquery нашел только цифры в элементе _li>a_, но обернуть их _"wrap"-ом_ не получается почему-то

Comment: @МайклМиллер Можно сделать так: <span class="тут ваш класс">(<?php echo $product_total; ?>)</span>  И задать классу стили. Или вы говорите про меню?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85582/discussion-between---and-alexander-semikashev).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я что-то не правильно понял. Но всё же попробую ответить.
Почему просто не создать папку в корне с названием каким нибудь. Например `include` и в нём `apple.php` и в нём хранить кол-во яблок. А на самой страничке подключать этот файл.

```
<?php 
include ('../include/apple.php')
?>
```

apple.php

```
<?php
$apple = 15;
?>
```

А в самом файле

```
<p>На складе <?php echo $apple ?> яблок.</p> // На складе 15 яблок.
```

Ну или в других частях страницы.

Comment: спасибо за внимание, добавлю сейчас ответ как сделал я костылем

Answer (score 0):

Если кому поможет:

Сделал скриптом

```
<script>
var count = $('.list-group-item.active').text();
var r = /\d+/;
$('.goods_counter span').text($('.list-group-item.active').text().match(r));
</script>
```

Короче - у активной категории есть класс **`.active`** из него скопировал текст в нужное место и оттуда удалил все кроме цифр (буквы, скобки, знаки препинания)